# Swap dates of appointment at the German embassy

Tags: visas, germany, embassies

A friend of mine got an earlier appointment date than me at the German embassy for a national visa application. We both have appointment dates already (mine will be in June, while his will be in April), however I need to have an earlier one. I asked him if I can take his slot and he agreed. Is it possible to request for an exchange of appointment dates?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to request for an exchange of appointment dates since it is possible to request for any kind of thing. However, I think you don't want to know whether it is possible to request the exchange of dates but whether it is possible to exchange the dates. Only the embassy can answer this question so you have to ask the embassy and not some random people on the internet.

Comment: @Neusser asking random people on the internet is the whole point of this website :) But I do agree OP should ask the consulate first.